# Read an XML node in namespace using Linq

Tags: vb.net, linq

How do I work out what the namespace declaration is for the Extension node?

I want to return all of the child nodes under: GPO->User->ExtensionData->Extension

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<GPO xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://www.microsoft.com/GroupPolicy/Settings">
  <User>
    <VersionDirectory>4</VersionDirectory>
    <VersionSysvol>4</VersionSysvol>
    <Enabled>true</Enabled>
    <ExtensionData>
      <Extension xmlns:q1="http://www.microsoft.com/GroupPolicy/Settings/Scripts" xsi:type="q1:Scripts">
        <q1:Script>
          <q1:Command>Logon.cmd</q1:Command>
          <q1:Type>Logon</q1:Type>
          <q1:Order>0</q1:Order>
          <q1:RunOrder>PSNotConfigured</q1:RunOrder>
        </q1:Script>
      </Extension>
      <Name>Scripts</Name>
    </ExtensionData>
  </User>
  <LinksTo>
    <SOMName>an interesting data value</SOMName>
    <SOMPath>some data value</SOMPath>
    <Enabled>true</Enabled>
    <NoOverride>false</NoOverride>
  </LinksTo>
</GPO>
```

This is my attempt:

```
Dim NS As XNamespace = "http://www.microsoft.com/GroupPolicy/Settings/Scripts"
Dim UserPolCount = XDoc.Descendants(NS + "Extension").First()
```

I get the following error: Sequence contains no elements

Also, the XML sample I have provided is only a small snippet, the ExtensionData->Extension nodes can be nested in different areas, so I was hoping to find the way of specifying the full path.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Extension` Element is still under the root namespace of:

```
http://www.microsoft.com/GroupPolicy/Settings
```

Elements under `Extension` are under the Scripts namespace:

```
http://www.microsoft.com/GroupPolicy/Settings/Scripts
```

So you need:

```
Dim NS As XNamespace = "http://www.microsoft.com/GroupPolicy/Settings/" 
Dim NS1 As XNamespace = "http://www.microsoft.com/GroupPolicy/Settings/Scipts" 
Dim UserPolCount = XDoc.Descendants(NS + "Extension").First() 
Dim ScriptNode = UserPolCount.Elements(NS1 + "Script")
```

**EDIT From the comments:**

```
Dim extension = 
    XDoc
    .Root
    .Element(NS + "User")
    .Element(NS + "ExtensionData")
    .Element(NS + "Extension");
```

Comment: thanks for the example. Can you tell me, how do I specify the path: GPO->User->ExtensionData->Extension and likewise GPO->Computer->ExtensionData->Extension

Answer (score 1):

You are using the wrong namespace. You need to use `http://www.microsoft.com/GroupPolicy/Settings` as the namespace.
The reason is that only the children of `Extension` are in the `Scripts` namespace. You can easily see this: The children are all prefixed with `q1`, the `Extension` tag itself not. Therefore it is defined in the default namespace, defined by the attribute `xmlns="http://www.microsoft.com/GroupPolicy/Settings"` on the root tag `GPO`.